# How to receive file with type csv from API response

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the export button which hit API and send response in .csv type. When i hit the API, the response said `status: 200` but i getting `HttpErrorResponse` in the console, and got this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
```

I have tried to ask my friend that I have to change my Header, but i don't understand how to do it properly. Should i set the header within Token Interceptor as same as when i set the token of the headers (if ya, how can I do that?)? Or how can i solve my problem?

This is the function that the button triggered:

```
onExport = () => {
    this._service.getDataExport(1, 1, this.filter).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        // const filename = `MediaPreparation.csv`;
        // const blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'text/csv' });
        // saveAs(blob, filename);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

This this is the service that I hit:

```
getDataExport = (page = 1, perPage = 1, filter = null): Observable<any> => {
   const _url = `${this.base_url}/api/v1/media-preparation/export`;

   return this.http.post(_url, {
     page : page.toString(),
     perPage: perPage.toString(),
     filter : filter
   });
}
```

and this is the Token Inteceptor:

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  intercept(req, next) {
    const authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    const tokenizedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.getToken()}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping, and I am sorry for the bad explanation, I stil beginner in Angular.

Comment: What do you want to do with the CSV file on the frontend? Is it to be downloadable for the client? - Most of the time the BE will handle files as CSV, and provide an endpoint which return json data. I am not sure why exactly you want the file on the FE. That might help answer your question. Cheers

Comment: @JonasPraem ya, i want to download the data as soon as the response is completed. Ah i have tried to change the content-type but i still got the same error

Answer (score 9):

The reason is easy, `HttpClient` is trying to parse your response as JSON, since it's the most common scenario and the default action.

To prevent `HttpClient` to parse your response, you have to put `responseType: 'text'` in your *httpOptions*:

```
private httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({}),
  responseType: 'text'
};
```

Then use this object as last parameter of your http method (I suppose get):

```
this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
  .subscribe(res => {
    // res is just a string, you have to split it on new lines and commas
    // or you can use a third part library
  });
```

**Note**:

Some servers may need to add some not-standard `Accept` header, for example:

```
headers: new HttpHeader({
  Accept: 'text/csv'
});
```

Or

```
headers: new HttpHeader({
  Accept: 'application/csv'
});
```

Or (standard but not semantic):

```
headers: new HttpHeader({
  Accept: 'plain/text'
});
```

Comment: It works mate, but i got new error in command prompt that said `"Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.` How can i fix that?

Comment: Just avoid any generic (no types between `<` and `>`)

Comment: Also possible `responseType: 'text' as' text'`